# Razor page form is not working with post request

Tags: .net, forms, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm learning .NET and I was trying to pass data from a simple form without tag-helpers, but the form doesn't work and I don't know why. It is very simple, a index file

```
@page
@model WebApplication1.Pages.IndexModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<form class="form-container" method="post">
    
    <input type="text" class="input-item" placeholder="Your First Name" name="FirstName">
    <input type="text" class="input-item" placeholder="Your Last Name" name="LastName">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Its model

```
namespace WebApplication1.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
       {
       }

       public IActionResult OnPost()
       {
           return RedirectToPage("Success");
       }

       public class InputModel
       {
           public string FirstName { get; set; }
        
           public string LastName{ get; set; }
      }  
   }
}
```

When it hit the post method it was suppose to redirect to the page Success.

Comment: _"When it hit the post method it was suppose to redirect to the page Success."_ What happens instead? Did you get an error message?

Comment: It gives HTTP ERROR 400

Comment: Can you  hit the post method successfully?If so,can you share your Success page OnGet method?

Comment: I can't hit the post method successfully. It gives the HTTP ERROR 400. I don't know why

Comment: Did you do something in middleware?I test with your code,and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 400 status code in Razor Pages is most often the result of a [failed request verification check](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/security/request-verification). The verification code is generated in a hidden field by the form tag helper when the method is set to post. If you have disabled tag helpers (or simply not enabled them), you can generate the token by including

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

within the form. Alternatively, you can disable request verification by adding the `IgnoreAntiforgeryToken` to the PageModel class:

```
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken(Order = 1001)]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <form method="post" class="login-form">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"><span
                                                class="fa fa-user"></span></div>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="FirstName" placeholder="FirstName"
                                            required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"><span
                                                class="fa fa-lock"></span></div>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" asp-for="LastName"
                                            placeholder="LastName" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <button type="submit" id="submitBtn"
                                            class="btn form-control btn-primary rounded submit px-3">Go!</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>

    //Login.cshtml.cs
    
    [BindProperty]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            LoginRequest request = new LoginRequest
            {
                FirstName = FirstName,
                LastName = LastName,
            };

            .
            .
            .
            
            if (..)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./Home");
            }

            
            return Page();
        }
```